# instantiateで生成したオブジェクトにボタンをつける

Tags: c#, unity3d

instantiateで生成したオブジェクトにボタンをつける方法はありますか??

具体的な手順は生成したオブジェクトを出してボタンをクリックするとオブジェクトが消える 
ものです

prefab化してspriterendererとbuttonをいれています

上記で実行してもボタンの機能はありませんでした

instantiateで生成したものはなぜかimageでは表示できずspriterendererでしかできないため 
後者でやってます。。

Answer (score 1):

Instantiateで生成したImageは、Canvasコンポーネントが付いたオブジェクトの子になっていますでしょうか。
　UIのImageコンポーネントを表示するには、Canvasコンポーネント以下にある必要があります。
　
　ボタンとしての機能がないという点に関しては、Hierarchy上にEventSystemがないのではないでしょうか。
　ボタンのインプットの判定にEventSystemが必要です。
　Unity上部のメニューの GameObject > UI > EventSystem で作成できます。
　
　CanvasやEventSystemは、Editor上でButtonやImageなどUGUIのオブジェクト作成時には自動で作成されます。
　ランタイム時にButtonやImageを生成する場合には、Hierarchy上のCanvasを検索してその子オブジェクトにしたり、EventSystemの有無の確認をする必要があります。
　もしくはCanvasやEventSystemも同様にInstantiateしてあげる必要があると思います。